# Centralizing Packages folder on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Hi I am running 2 copies of sublime text 2. One on a windows box and another on a laptop running ubuntu.
I am wondering if it is possible to  move the sublime packages folder to a shared location. I only use one machine at any given time but it would be nice if the packages/snippets etc were consistent across both environments.
Any one had any luck with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 may hold write lock on the files of the settings files, so sharing files might not work as intended if you are trying to use them from multiple locations *simultaneously*.

However, it is possible to share settings and on UNIX users do it via symlinks (mklink on Windows). I am pretty sure you cannot set the path of the config files from Sublime itself, so you need to instead do some kind of file-system trickery.

But as the recommended method I'd use some file sharing service like Dropbox which will also automatically keep back-ups from your files in the case you manage to destroy them within Sublime Text 2 accidentally:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/24/sync-and-back-up-sublime-text-settings-and-plug-ins-using-dropbox-on-linux-and-osx/ (have pointers for OSX, Linux, Windows)

Also I am not sure if there is anything operating system specific in those configs, but I can confirm it works 100% if you are using the same OS.